# RPM for suse linux named libatomic1

Tags: linux, rpm, suse, zypper

> my os info is; NAME="SLES" VERSION="15-SP3" VERSION_ID="15.3"
> PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3" ID="sles"
> ID_LIKE="suse" ANSI_COLOR="0;32" CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:15:sp3"
> when i do

```
$rpm -q libatomic1
```

> it reply package libatomic1 is not installed, and when i run

```
$sudo zypper install libatomic1
```

> it raise Loading repository data... Reading installed packages...
> 'libatomic1' not found in package names. Trying capabilities. No
> provider of 'libatomic1' found. Resolving package dependencies...
> Nothing to do
>
> please assist how can i install this rpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [SuSE page](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?package=libatomic1&project=devel%3Agcc) this is the procedure (executed by `root`)

```
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:gcc/SLE-15/devel:gcc.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install libatomic1
```

Comment: thanks for assist.